# Looking for Raspberry Pi pinout image map showing all components

Tags: gpio, hardware

I'm looking for a link to a picture of a Raspberry Pi that has HTML pop-ups (mouseover and it tells you *exactly* what everything was depending on what you  mouse was over). I can't remember what exactly I'm talking about - the right term is eluding me. Image map? I think that's it but I'm probably wrong!

It was a nice webpage that shows me what *everything* on the Raspbery Pi does. Generally, it shows users what "that thing that looks like blah and is next to that other thing in that place on the board" actually is.

*Example*

- Mouseover the 8 through-pin holes right under that GPIO pins? Tells you what they are, down to hole-by-hole accuracy.
- Mouseover a capacitor? Tells you *which* capacitor it is and what it does (simplified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched for "Raspberry Pi component map" and found [this site](http://raspmap.tsar.in/). Embedding it loses the mouse-over functionality but this is the image they use.

[image: Raspberry Pi board layout]

Comment: God, I must've tried a couple dozen different word combos, and I couldn't find it to save my life. The word "components" was apparently the key. Thanks! That's the exact link I was looking for.

Comment: Lucky guess! Great link by the way. I'm fairly new to Raspi and hardware in general so this is a real help.

Comment: Yeah man, I hear ya. I have the main GPIO pins listed out on a (custom-made) poster, but I *really* needed the P5  header(didn't know the term at the time, and Google was useless!) pinout.